# How should I architect Nodejs & MySQL for SaaS application

Tags: saas

I am creating a SaaS application using Nodejs & MySQL. My application is a project management software on the lines of basecamp.

Below are few of the possibilities to structure my code & would appreciate if you can guide me which I should use it.

1) Put all SQL queries in Stored Procedure & simply use Nodejs to pass parameter & call SP. This will avoid multiple DB calls for a big operation requiring data with different queries.

2) Use ORM model. I am not so cleared about the usage of ORM in my context. But plz inform if for such an application is it the right choice?

Thanks

Comment: Definitely go with ORM. You can still avoid multiple database queries by using JOIN on multiple tables.

Comment: Andre thanks for reply. Right now using MVC style I have created my own structure for database access & it is working fine. I have heavily used stored procedures. Is this approach right for scaling my SaaS app?

Comment: if you want to switch databases, you'll land in trouble using stored procedures. For all practical purposes, use ORM.